# CMake build failure on rtosc when liblo is linked on MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, porting

I'm trying to build [rtosc](https://github.com/fundamental/rtosc) which uses liblo, ci branch on MSVC. While building, ran into this warning

`LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/LC:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib'; ignored [D:\BuildAndGit\zynaddsubfx\rtosc\build\liblo.vcxproj]`

which leads to lots of errors

```
Building Custom Rule D:/BuildAndGit/zynaddsubfx/rtosc/CMakeLists.txt liblo.c LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/LC:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib'; ignored  
[D:\BuildAndGit\zynaddsubfx\rtosc\build\liblo.vcxproj] LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/llo'; ignored  
[D:\BuildAndGit\zynaddsubfx\rtosc\build\liblo.vcxproj] liblo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol lo_message_new referenced in function speed_liblo_write 
[D:\BuildAndGit\zynaddsubfx\rtosc\build\liblo.vcxproj] liblo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol lo_message_free referenced in function speed_liblo_write 
[D:\BuildAndGit\zynaddsubfx\rtosc\build\liblo.vcxproj] liblo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol lo_message_add_int32 referenced in function speed_liblo_write   
[D:\BuildAndGit\zynaddsubfx\rtosc\build\liblo.vcxproj] liblo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol lo_message_add_float referenced in function speed_liblo_write 
[D:\BuildAndGit\zynaddsubfx\rtosc\build\liblo.vcxproj] liblo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol lo_message_add_string referenced in function speed_liblo_write 
[D:\BuildAndGit\zynaddsubfx\rtosc\build\liblo.vcxproj] liblo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol lo_message_get_argv referenced in function speed_liblo_read  
[D:\BuildAndGit\zynaddsubfx\rtosc\build\liblo.vcxproj] liblo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol lo_message_serialise referenced in function speed_liblo_write 
[D:\BuildAndGit\zynaddsubfx\rtosc\build\liblo.vcxproj] liblo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol lo_message_deserialise referenced in function speed_liblo_read  
[D:\BuildAndGit\zynaddsubfx\rtosc\build\liblo.vcxproj] liblo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol lo_bundle_new referenced in function main 
[D:\BuildAndGit\zynaddsubfx\rtosc\build\liblo.vcxproj] liblo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol lo_bundle_add_message referenced in function main  
[D:\BuildAndGit\zynaddsubfx\rtosc\build\liblo.vcxproj] liblo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol lo_bundle_serialise referenced in function main 
[D:\BuildAndGit\zynaddsubfx\rtosc\build\liblo.vcxproj] liblo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol lo_bundle_free referenced in function main 
[D:\BuildAndGit\zynaddsubfx\rtosc\build\liblo.vcxproj]   
[D:\BuildAndGit\zynaddsubfx\rtosc\build\Debug\liblo.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 12 unresolved externals D:\BuildAndGit\zynaddsubfx\rtosc\build\liblo.vcxproj]
```

Looked for where `/L` is being called in cmake and source files but didn't find anything.

Edit: found some more info that `-L` is a gcc flag and the flag I should be using is `/LIBPATH` but I still don't know where to look for. Looked for it in all cmake files, didn't find it.

Comment: my guess would be a vcpkg toolchain file which was generated for a different compiler